# log4net - how to call ActivateOptions on AdoNetAppenderParameter.Layout

Tags: log4net, log4net-appender

I am trying to configure log4net dynamically for writing log to sql database. For that I am using AdoNetAppender class from log4net library.

I see activateOptions for the appender but not for the Layout defined in Command Parameters

```
public override void ActivateOptions();
```

Calling AdoNetAppender.ActivateOptions() is writing logs to database but its **writing same data to all columns**, instead of **writing to corresponding data to respective columns**.

I figured this has to do with ActiveOptions on Layout, but I don't see ActivateOptions for Layout.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show your code and any applicable config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing this issue. Below fix did the trick:

```
public class CustomAdoNetAppender : AdoNetAppender
{
         //code omitted for simplicity
         //parameter using inherited layout
         AddParameter(new AdoNetAppenderParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@thread",
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
            Size = 255,
            Layout = new CustomLayout2RawLayoutAdapter(new PatternLayout() { ConversionPattern = "%thread" })
        });
}

private class CustomLayout2RawLayoutAdapter : Layout2RawLayoutAdapter
    {
        private readonly PatternLayout _layout;
        public CustomLayout2RawLayoutAdapter(PatternLayout layout)
            : base(layout)
        {
            _layout = layout;
        }

        public void ActivateOptions()
        {
            _layout.ActivateOptions();
        }
    }

 public override void ActivateOptions()
    {
        base.ActivateOptions();

        if (m_usePreparedCommand)
        {
            foreach (AdoNetAppenderParameter item in m_parameters)
            {
                if (item.Layout is CustomLayout2RawLayoutAdapter)
                    (item.Layout as CustomLayout2RawLayoutAdapter).ActivateOptions();
            }
        }
    }
```